# Linking error when upgrading from lua 4.0.1 to 5.1.4

Tags: c++, lua, linker-errors

I'm working on a really old source code (compiled in Red Hat). Before it had lua-4.0.1 so I just compiled the latest lua (lua-5.1.4) and installed it in the same directory as the old one. The implementation isn't very big so there wasn't much to change except a few function names and I had to include "lauxlib.h" to get it to compile. It compiles without any problems but it gives these linking errors.

```
/usr/local/lib/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_load':
loadlib.o(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `dlopen'
loadlib.o(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_sym':
loadlib.o(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `dlsym'
loadlib.o(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/usr/local/lib/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_unloadlib':
loadlib.o(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `dlclose'
```

Basically all the paths are correct but I use the same flags for the compiler as the old one, I havent changed the makefile at all.

```
-static -lpthread -lnsl -lutil -ldl -lmysqlclient -llua -llualib -lz -lcppunit
```

The ldl flag is already there.

I just want to know things to try. Everything is appreciated. This is driving me insane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place `-ldl` at the end of the liner command. The order is important.

The linker searches for libraries fulfilling  an unreferenced symbol only in libs which are standing more right on the command line. Your new `liblua.a` now uses `dlopen` and friends, while the older didn't. Since `-ldl` is left of `-llua`, the linker does not use libdl to link the lua references.